# Problems with executable jar and WebServices

Tags: web-services, soap, executable-jar

I'm trying to execute a jar file and when I do it I have this error and I don't know to solve it, when I see the trace I don't know what does it means. Ihave two ws one where I connect to a mysql database and another one to a sqlserver database and I have this, please, could you help me?:

```
C:\Users\cmorales\Desktop>java -jar SincroCloud2.jar
Ejecutando el exe
ago 28, 2012 10:59:16 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
Advertencia: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and j
avax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
AxisFault 
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode:
faultString: org.apache.axis.InternalException: java.lang.Exception: Couldn't f
ind a matching Java operation for WSDD operation &quot;procesosProgramados&quot;
(1 args)
faultActor:
faultNode:
faultDetail:
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:UW-000216


org.apache.axis.InternalException: java.lang.Exception: Couldn't find a matching
Java operation for WSDD operation "procesosProgramados" (1 args)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder
.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.
java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(Deserializ
ationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endEleme
nt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(U
nknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next
(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Un
known Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown S
ource)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(Deserialization
Context.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnders
tandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at es.uniway.wscloud.WscloudSoapBindingStub.procesosProgramados(WscloudS
oapBindingStub.java:368)
    at es.uniway.principal.ObtenerProcesos.ejecutar(ObtenerProcesos.java:25)

    at es.uniway.principal.SincronizadorCloud.main(SincronizadorCloud.java:1
4)
```

Why I have this?. Thanks so much

---

I have solved this including the jars but now when I execute this jar I have this issue. This executable have two webservices one of them with a mysql database, the another one to connect to a sqlserver database. What does this issue mean?, where I have the NullPointerException?.

```
C:\Users\cmorales\Desktop>java -jar SincroCloud2.jar
Ejecutando el exe
AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode:
faultString: java.lang.NullPointerException
faultActor:
faultNode:
faultDetail:
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:UW-000216

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder
.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.
java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(Deserializ
ationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endEleme
nt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(U
nknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next
(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Un
known Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown S
ource)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(Deserialization
Context.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnders
tandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at es.uniway.wscloud.WscloudSoapBindingStub.procesosProgramados(WscloudS
oapBindingStub.java:338)
    at es.uniway.principal.ObtenerProcesos.ejecutar(ObtenerProcesos.java:25)

    at es.uniway.principal.SincronizadorCloud.main(SincronizadorCloud.java:1
4)

C:\Users\cmorales\Desktop>
```

Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is missing the java mail API and JAF API.  You can download those below here:

[JAF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-135046.html#download)
[Java Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html)

Without a bit more detail, I'm not sure if that'll fix your issue though.  If you made the jar file, you can try repackaging it with the above APIs. Also you could add them to the classpath and try running the jar again too.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was solved adding this jar, but now I have a new problem with the connection to the database with a Connection refused: connect.